# Scenario outline step definition is not reachable and also UndefinedThrowable

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

In my Scenario outline with Examples data,  feature file, I can't navigate or run the steps with included Example column. See as shown.
[image: Feature file pic]
The initial steps under 'Given' keyword are able to be navigable and invoked fine, during normal run. The blue color 'username', 'password', and 'facility' are coming from Excel file. Where as the yellow color highlighted steps which contains the Scenario Outline Examples-columns are neither navigable, nor recognizable by the Cucumber run time. They display this message for each step: `io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedThrowable: This step is undefined`
I am using the latest IntelliJ IDE with latest cucumber plugin.

Comment: Can you also give the step definition of the yellow highlighted steps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is with respect to the step definition like for
And User enters recipient as recipient_email

```
And("^ User enters recipient as recipient_email(.*)$")
public void userEntersRecipientasRecipient_Email(String email){
//-----implementation------//
}
```